# Get Date range from week number and year where each week starts on Sunday using JS

Tags: javascript, date-range, week-number

I have the following code to get the start and end date of a week

```
Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
  var date = new Date(this.getTime());
  date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  // Thursday in current week decides the year.
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 3 - (date.getDay() + 6) % 7);
  // January 4 is always in week 1.
  var week1 = new Date(date.getFullYear(), 0, 4);
  // Adjust to Thursday in week 1 and count number of weeks from date to week1.
  return 1 + Math.round(((date.getTime() - week1.getTime()) / 86400000 - 3 + (week1.getDay() + 6) % 7) / 7);
}

function getDateRangeOfWeek(weekNo, y){
    var d1, numOfdaysPastSinceLastMonday, rangeIsFrom, rangeIsTo;
    d1 = new Date(''+y+'');
    numOfdaysPastSinceLastMonday = d1.getDay() - 1;
    d1.setDate(d1.getDate() - numOfdaysPastSinceLastMonday);
    d1.setDate(d1.getDate() + (7 * (weekNo - d1.getWeek())));
    rangeIsFrom = (d1.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + d1.getDate() + "-" + d1.getFullYear();
    d1.setDate(d1.getDate() + 6);
    rangeIsTo = (d1.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + d1.getDate() + "-" + d1.getFullYear() ;
    return rangeIsFrom + " to " + rangeIsTo;
};
```

But in here the week start from monday. How can I achieve the same where each week start from sunday?

Comment: Since you calculate `numOfdaysPastSinceLastMonday` it is not really surprising, that your function results in a week from monday to monday

Comment: How can I get the it for Sunday @Scorpioo590

Comment: `numOfDaysPastSinceLastSunday = d1.getDay();`
This also prevents said variable of becoming negative for sundays.

Comment: This doesn't work @Scorpioo590

Comment: What is the output then?

Comment: If I input week number as 1 and year as 2018 the range is 1-8-2017 to 1-14-2017 @Scorpioo590

Comment: `getWeek()` of 01-01-2018 will result 52. Thus in line 5 of the function you jump back 51 weeks thus getting a result in 2017

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197253/discussion-between-tharindu-and-scorpioo590).